# creating working seach Command form with Tab Control In MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, tabs, vba

I am a learner in VBA and MS Acess and I have been working on Creating A Record of activities and records of claim in my office. i have tried different VBAs that i saw online but all of them seem to only work for a simple form and not a form with a TAB control(form with Tabs on top. Each tab brings out Basic information, Time frames, payment Info and Distribution Info.

I placed a search Text Box and Button at the header and have used various VBA Codes pasted online. But none envisaged a Multi-Tabed form. I am referencing a Table named "tblClaimEntry" and my Multi-Tab (Tab Control) form named "frmEntryForm". A claim Number(in a Table field named "CLAIM NO") has been assigned as a primary key. i wan it that when the claim no (e.g CL/MOPM/17/04/05832/HQR) is typed in the textbox and we click the button or press enter, it would pull out the relevant record registered against that claim no.regardless of the Tab in am since they all source from the same row of record

Please help with the VBA code below; it works up to but is not pulling out the current record correlating to the entered claim no:[my macro. the Text bos name is "txtKeywords" and the Search Button is BtnSearch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyKUs.png)

Comment: Sub-form with the source for the data using select * from claim entry with the criteria being the text box.  You need to have a go at the code here, it's not a code writing service :)

Comment: Use of tab control is irrelevant to the search code. Edit question to provide attempted code for analysis.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Please check my Macro and help see what is wrong. thank you

Comment: @June7 Please check my Macro and help see what is wrong. thank you

Comment: The image will not open for me. Post the actual code, not an image.

Comment: @June7Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private Sub BtnSearch_Click ()
 Dim rs As Recordset
 Dim db As Database
 Dim strKeywords As String
 Dim strSearch As String

 Set db = CurrentDb
 Set re = db.OpenRecordset (“tblClaimEntry”, dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
If IsNull (Me! [txtKeywords]) Or (Me! [txtKeywords]) = “ ” Then
MsgBox “Please enter a value!”, vbOkOnly, “Invalid Search Criterion!”
Me! [TxtKeywords].SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

Comment: rs.FindFirst “CLAIMNO=’ ” & Me.txtKeywords & “ ‘ “

If rs.NoMatch = True Then
msgBox “Please Check Again. No record found”, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, “Sorry”
 Me.txtKeywords.SetFocus

End If

End Sub